# Number of increasing integer sequences which may be sides of a convex $k$-gon

Tags: co.combinatorics

We need to find the total number of sequences $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$, $x_1<\dots<x_k$, $x_i\in \{1,\dots,N\}$, such that $x_1+\dots+x_{k-1}>x_k$.

Comment: I edited the question, and now it looks less or more reasonable.